# gl_NormalMatrix and gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix in GLES 2.0 (WebGL)

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

Are gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix and gl_NormalMatrix matrices (or similar forms) supported in OpenGL ES 2.0? That's computed automatically by GL, provided the modelview matrix and the initial matrix and then automatically passed to the vertex shader?

Thanks,

-Ilyes

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't have any built-in matrices or variables (except for gl_Position), so you have to calculate them by yourself and upload them to the shader as uniform variables.

Comment: This isn't convenient, especially in an embedded system where GLES 2 is accessed via a JS API (WebGL). Updating the relevant matcies kind of take a lot of time (going through the JS interpreter then the native GL bindings, etc.) Are there ways to speed up things a bit?

Comment: @Ilyes Is not a matter of convenience, it's how the API is designed. I really doubt calculating some matrices will make a performance problema.

Answer (score 0):

gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix, you can use ViewProjectMatrix uniformly send from the OpenGL application to the shader.

gl_NormalMatrix, try using WorldViewInverseTranspose again send uniformly from the application.